# Magento 2: How to give Admin Input Field Validation

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, validation, magento2.1.5

I have below code

```
$this->addColumn(
                    'qty[]', [
                'header' => __('Qty'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'qty',
                'editor' => 'text',
                'class' => 'validate-number',
                    ]
            );
```

How to validate this field. I need to validate for only numbers allowed?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add:

```
'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
```

Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php`

Comment: Hi @Khoa If u look at Admin Create Order functionality & inspect actually class is not applying & They are doing validation on server side Strange. So what's need to apply this

Comment: On server side how to validate it?

Comment: Okay! Let me try.

Comment: How you create this custom field? it is a custom attribute?

Comment: This is listing field. Not attribute

Comment: There is a note, for the Js validation form, you should debug: `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/web/order/create/scripts.js` in your static content.